# Is the Google Translate phone app using Tesseract to do OCR locally?

Tags: android, ios, ocr, tesseract, google-translate

The application is super fast and accurate at OCR, compare to a test I wrote on iOS with Tesseract.
So I wonder:
Is the Google Translate phone applications using Tesseract to do OCR locally? Or is it calling some Google backend such as Google Drive API, which support OCR.
Anyone from Google or that team knows?

Comment: Yes, I believe Google does use the Tesseract library for their Google Translate application. A quick search will yield results for OCR libraries. Here is a link to just one: http://antimatter15.com/ocrad.js/demo.html

Comment: Thank you @chRyNaN . I'm very impressed by the performance and accuracy of Google Translate compare to what I wrote with Tesseract, so that's why I'm asking specifically about the Google Translate phone app.

Comment: I'm not positive as I am not a Google engineer, but I am fairly certain that they use Tesseract on the server for even Google Drive API. OCR is a pretty complex task and with their support of the Tesseract library, I highly doubt they would use a completely different one for their applications (perhaps slightly modified but most likely just wrapper code). Also, there is enough resources online that hint they do use Tesseract. As to your code, there may be many reasons as to why the performance and accuracy is not there.

Comment: I'm not affiliated to Google in any way, but work for another mobile OCR company. According to different sources on the web Google acquired World Lens developer which has it's own mobile OCR, and I would guess that in newer versions of Google Translate they use this other mobile OCR. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_Lens

Answer (score 0):

I think Google is using their new Deep Learning Library [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org) for the new OCR stuff. Convolutional Neuronal Network (CNN) are the new State of the Art methodologies for OCR.

Google also wrote a blog post on their research blog about how they are using Deep Learning and CNN's in their new Translate App ([Link to blog post](http://googleresearch.blogspot.co.at/2015/07/how-google-translate-squeezes-deep.html))